# Where is Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Syntax.Identifier defined?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing a Roslyn code fix and I want to replace an identifier token. To do that I'm finding the token and then creating a new one

```
var newToken = SyntaxFactory.Token(identifierToken.LeadingTrivia, SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken, newName, newName, identifierToken.TrailingTrivia);
```

However, at run time I'm getting this error

```
System.ArgumentException: Use Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Syntax.Identifier or Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Syntax.VerbatimIdentifier to create identifier tokens.
```

I hunted down the package for that and found that it was now [unlisted](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp/). I assume that I'm using a lot of old Roslyn stuff because the templates are old. I went and ran a wholesale nuget update against the project but that didn't seem to work very well. What is the modern approach for this? Are there any updated analyzer template floating around out there?

Comment: It looks like you're using an ancient version of Roslyn.  Upgrade to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SyntaxFactory.Identifier(...) and SyntaxFactory.VerbatimIdentifier(...) are what you are looking for.